# Removing the arrow in a HTML5 LibGDX Game

Tags: java, html, libgdx

Every time I export a game or prototype to HTML to test it always has this really ugly and obscuring [arrow button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAoz2.png) on the top left of the screen.

I can't seem to find any way to remove this and I can't find anywhere where I can look to see how to do it or if it is even possible to remove it. If somebody could explain this I'd be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index.html`: remove the `<a class="superdev" ... >` line.

Comment: Thanks **so** much.